# Intellij WAR Project says class not found in other system.

Tags: war, classnotfoundexception

My Project build in **Intellij** with maven and compiles fine and deployed in tomcat nothing problem in local system (window)
But after deployed war file in **linux** system. I tried to access method that throws, exception class not found.

```
exception  
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.uadetector.service.UADetectorServiceFactory  
root cause  

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.uadetector.service.UADetectorServiceFactory
```

I can see there are libraries in WAR excluded directory in linux (where I deployed)
[image]

**My Code**

```
UserAgentStringParser parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser();
ReadableUserAgent agent = parser.parse(httpServletRequest.getHeader("User-Agent"));
```

What might be the problem please say some solution